# How to trace Mongoose query execution time

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to create trace spans of my node.js with Mongoose application. One specific trace I would like to get is how long one Mongoose query, update or document.save method takes time.

What I know is that Mongoose has pre and post hooks for these methods: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html

However I'm struggling to find a good example how to keep timer in context between the hooks so that I get the trace of one and the same operation execution. Is there a good way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
schema.pre('find', function() {
  this._startTime = Date.now();
});

schema.post('find', function() {
  if (this._startTime != null) {
    console.log('Runtime in MS: ', Date.now() - this._startTime);
  }
});
```

**Reference From:** https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6376#issuecomment-385083763

Comment: I was thinking something like this but if I call Model.find twice in a row is it guaranteed that `post` hook will be called in the same order?

Comment: order might vary depends on the query execution time, but it will bind this property so you can console query info to understand for what query it is showing the result

Comment: Ok got it, thank you! And in document middleware such as `save` this is bind to document.

Answer (score 0):

Use Insomnia, this will let you know the total time a query used to run, but most time it depend on your network and if you are working with local mongoDB or online. Hope it help

Comment: That's not what I'm after. I want to trace all my methods from the point where api were invoked all the way down to point where Mongoose operation is called. I already have traces of my controller execution but I want to trace each Mongoose operation separately inside my controller.